# how can i change a nickname of a user on discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, edit

i was trying to change nicknames on discord.py 1.7.3 but i'd tried some times in different ways but don't have success

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import urllib.request
import json
import datetime as DT
import configparser
import os
from discord.utils import get

class Search(commands.Cog):

@commands.command()
async def search(self, ctx, option, *, name):
for member in ctx.guild.members:
              if(member.nick == name):
                await member.edit(nick="teste")
```

also, i tried start with:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def search(self, ctx, option, *, name, discMember: discord.Member):
```

and fail too, when i use "discMember: dscord.Member", the code stop running, don't know why doesn't work

Comment: ok, guys, i realized that bot need a higher role then the target who u want to update nickname

Answer (score 1):

```py
@commands.command()
async def change_nick(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await member.edit(nick="test")
```

The  you can use this command by typing something like `[your_prefix]change_nick @Member#1234` in a chat. Where `[you_prefix]` is you bot's prefix and `@Member#1234` is a member mention.

Answer (score 1):

ok, guys, i realized that bot need a higher role then the target who u want to update nickname.

so, nothing is wrong with the code.